# Exploring fluent wait mechanism for Page Factory @FindAll List<WebElement> along with AjaxElementLocatorFactory

Tags: selenium

Can someone share his/her experience on Page Factory wait mechanism for below scenario of `List<WebElement>` where 5 element's `xpath` are incorrect.

**What would be waiting time here ? 5 Seconds or 25 Seconds or something else is going on inside code.**

Lets say, Setting 10 Sec wait using :

```
AjaxElementLocatorFactory ajaxElemFactory = new  AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 10);
```

But not using selenium implicit wait.

if i write below code -

```
**@FindAll({    
    @FindBy(css = HomePageLocators.megaMenu1),
    @FindBy(xpath = HomePageLocators.anntaylorImage2),
    @FindBy(css = HomePageLocators.megaMenu3),
    @FindBy(xpath = HomePageLocators.anntaylorImage4),
    @FindBy(xpath = HomePageLocators.anntaylorImage5),
}) public List<WebElement> pageLoadCondition;**
```

lets assume all locators are wrong (incorrect xpath) if i print pageLoadCondition.size then it prints 0 and empty list is returned.

Hope `AjaxElementLocatorFactory` would not come into picture here as we are not performing any action on the element.

Now foucs moves to next line in code i.e. (Explicit wait of 5 Sec)

```
wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>((WebDriver) driver).withTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(pageLoadCondition));
```

Then would it wait for maximum of 5 seconds for searching 5 elements of the list OR would it really wait for 5*5 = 25 second to traverse and check presence of each elements of list one by one.

Comment: Someone can please share his or her understanding on this.

Comment: Any input would be appreciated

Comment: @Fenio, can you please share your experience on this post.